# Compute device position using AR

Tags: java, android, android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore

First of all, I know the position when I start the AR session.
So I'm in A point with my lat-lon; I walk for some meters and I want my position in B point without using GPS or other techniques, only using ARCore.
I've tried using poses for the angle and distance but I have a big error...

The error It's like of 5.3815 meters after doing a path of 20 meters.
I don't know if it is normal or there are some errors in my code.

`initialBearingAR = LocationScene.deviceOrientation.azimuth;`

So it's the orientation calculated using sensors

```
double distanceAR = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((camPose1.tx() - camPose2.tx()),2)/ 2.0 +
                     Math.pow((camPose1.ty() - camPose2.ty()),2) / 2.0 +
                     Math.pow((camPose1.tz() - camPose2.tz()),2) / 2.0);
```

camPose1 is the Pose calculated at the point A and camPose2 is the pose calculated at the point B. Both are the pose of the camera

```
double[] latLonEnd = travel(latStartAR, lonStartAR, initialBearingAR, distanceAR);
```

`latEndAR = latLonEnd[0];lonEndAR = latLonEnd[1]`

The travel method:

```
 public double[] travel(double qrLat, double qrLon , double initialBearing, double distance) {
        double bR = Math.toRadians(initialBearing);
        distance = distance/1000;
        double lat1R = Math.toRadians(qrLat);
        double lon1R = Math.toRadians(qrLon);
        double dR = distance/6371.01; //Mettere diviso radius earth

        double a = Math.sin(dR) * Math.cos(lat1R);
        double lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1R) * Math.cos(dR) + a * Math.cos(bR));
        double lon2 = lon1R
                + Math.atan2(Math.sin(bR) * a, Math.cos(dR) - Math.sin(lat1R) * Math.sin(lat2));
        double[] latlon = new double[2];
        latlon[0] = Math.toDegrees(lat2);
        latlon[1] = Math.toDegrees(lon2);
        return latlon;
    }
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you share details how you do the calculations and how big the error is?

Comment: I've put it in the question now, also with my code